# Vega chart count aggregation displays nothing if data values is empty array, how to fix this?

Tags: json, visualization, data-analysis, vega-lite, vega

I have this small Vega chart spec which should display the count of the FieldToCount:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "encoding": {
    "text": {
      "aggregate": "count",
      "field": "FieldToCount"
    }
  },
  "data": {"values": [{"FieldToCount": 1}, {"FieldToCount": 1}]},
  "mark": {
    "type": "text",
    "fontSize": 20
  }
}
```

This works but as soon as I have zero item in the values it displays nothing. So this does not work:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "encoding": {
    "text": {
      "aggregate": "count",
      "field": "FieldToCount"
    }
  },
  "data": {"values": []},
  "mark": {
    "type": "text",
    "fontSize": 20
  }
}
```

So the question is how to make sure it displays 0?

Comment: Marks are drawn for each data point. No data points means no marks are drawn.

Comment: @DavideBacci That is a good explanation of the issue, thanks, however I still don't have any clue where to go with this to display 0 if empty.

Comment: I'll add an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"values": [{"FieldToCount": 1}, {"FieldToCount": 1}]},
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {"values": [{"q": 1}]},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "condition": {"test": "length(data('source_0')) > 0", "value": ""},
          "value": "0"
        }
      },
      "mark": {"type": "text", "fontSize": 20}
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"aggregate": [{"op": "count", "field": "FieldToCount", "as": "c"}]}
      ],
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "c"}},
      "mark": {"type": "text", "fontSize": 20}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If I put an empty array into the data values field it still shows nothing: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaAXQC+SwUgCecAE5HQcWVDbKassmlCY4AD0xeIC6ybpjs8pogPhAB6IJOZPQAFKrqSQDkMgy2UHAA+gAM6QCUxQAEAHxlBYog2rpwaCAg5nU6ek01pq3ItgDWgZhWOI3oPv61AGZymADKNABeowBMBd0K3rZIshDTtggOIEhkZLZ8PodsOE0uDLIBSpM0cILKTQBiz68AKmwAwmw7g8jgZ0FAWmZjEonC43B5Bn5YqAni83mCWj0kP1BsNRlFEVMZvMlmhVt0zEA

Comment: You didn't copy my code exactly. You're missing an extra data definition on one of the layers.  "data": {"values": [{"q": 1}]},

Comment: Yeah sorry the Vega editor did not refresh when I changed the array and I tried to do some changes. Now it is working perfectly!